# getting the access token from mgt-login with globalProvider.getAccessToken. How do i get a refresh token?

Tags: microsoft-graph-toolkit

My frontend users are logging in with `<mgt-login>`

then i fetch their access token with

```
const msAccessToken = await Providers.globalProvider.getAccessToken({ scopes: this.scopes });
```

Now i send that token to the backend and make a graph client using `'@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client'` something like this.

```
const client = Client.init({
            authProvider: async (done) => {
                try {
                    done(null, delegatedAccessToken as string);
                } catch (err) {
                    console.log(' 6312', err);
                    done(err, null);
                }
            },
            debugLogging: true
        });
        return client;
```

#### problem

If the frontend user stays logged in for a long period of time then they trigger backend activity. the client cannot be made due to an expired token

> Error: Access token has expired or is not yet valid

simply refreshing the frontend and trying the backend client again will work.

How can i refresh the access token on frontend or backend. Or at least how do i extend the expiration date?

Comment: On the frontend, mgt doesn't support refreshing the token. In the backend though, you can explore requesting the token which comes back with a refresh token. In the event a backend activity is triggered, and the token is expired, you refresh with the refresh token, do the activity and update the frontend. Generally, that's hacky so I would advise, based on your app architecture, to just reload the app and get a new token. Another option, make the graph calls with the provider https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/providers/providers#making-your-own-calls-to-microsoft-graph